# How to input strings correctly to be parsed as a JSON in bash?

Tags: json, bash, github-api

I get a "Problems parsing JSON" message when I try to run my code and I'm not sure why because it makes sense (at least to me):

```
#!/bin/bash

LAST_TAG_NAME=$(curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPONAME/releases/latest' | sed -n '/tag_name/{ s/[^:]*:[\ ]*\([^,]*\),/\1/; p; }' | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')
LAST_TAG_NUMBER=$(echo ${LAST_TAG_NAME} | grep -o '\..*' | sed -e 's/^.//')
TAG_NAME="api-web-${YEAR}w${WEEK}"
CURRENT_NUM=$((LAST_TAG_NUMBER + 1))
FINAL_NAME="$TAG_NAME.$CURRENT_NUM"

curl -u USERNAME:TOKEN -X POST 'https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPONAME/releases' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript' --data-binary '{"tag_name": $FINAL_NAME}'
```

Basically, all the variable stuff works.  TAG_NAME is something that looks like api-web-2017w42 and CURRENT_NUM would just be some number like 2.  The problem only exits once I try to create a new release.  Note that USERNAME and REPONAME were anonymized.

Comment: The problem is with `$FINAL_NAME`. It doesn't expand, so server receives `{"tag_name": $FINAL_NAME}`, which is invalid JSON. Use `'{"tag_name": "'"$FINAL_NAME"'"}'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

While your specific issue was variable expansion as pointed by @randomir, you can use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) JSON parser which is like sed for JSON to process your JSON data result. With this you don't need to create json object manually :

```
year=2017
week=42
user=bertrandmartel
repo=speed-test-lib

final_name=$(curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/$user/$repo/releases/latest" | \
     jq -r --arg year $year --arg week $week \
     '. | .tag_name | 
      { 
         tag_name: (
            "api-web-" + $year + "w" + $week + "." + 
            (((split(".")[1] | tonumber) + 1) | tostring)
         ) 
      }')

echo "$final_name"

curl -u USERNAME:TOKEN \
     "https://api.github.com/repos/$user/$repo/releases" \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "$final_name"
```